# join two different tables?

Tags: mysql

How can I join table `a` and table `b` and get records for each? Not an actual join... not sure what this is called.

So if I have 3 records in `a`, and 5 records in `b`, I want 8 records back.

In a record for `a`, all `b` fields can be null. In a record for `b`, all `a` fields can be null.

---

**edit: My tables have different fields.**

```
Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

Comment: The error is because your both select don't have the same columns. They have to be the same type and in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the others mentionned, you need an union

```
SELECT intColumn, varcharColumn, intColumn FROM a
UNION
SELECT intColumn, varcharColumn, 0 FROM b
```

but you must have the same number of columns and they must also have similar data types.

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) a good tutorial about it

Also, if you want columns that are not in both tables, you can fill with nulls or constants.

Comment: Can I deal with my columns being different by selecting null values to make them match? `SELECT NULL as field_that_this_table_doesnt_have`

Comment: Yes you can, I updated my answer. You can add constants in your select. I don't have MySQL but it works in sql server 2010, i just tried.

Answer (score 1):

You want a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html):

```
SELECT something FROM a
UNION
SELECT something FROM b
```

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` to be sure that duplicates are not removed if the tables contain the same values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id1 = b.id2
UNION
SELECT * FROM a
RIGHT JOIN b ON a.id1 = b.id2
```

Just make sure, that A and B have different IDs

Edit: [**Working Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd093/1/0)

You can also use some other field other then `id` which are not same in two table

Edit: Updated fiddle